# Unable to select the data from dropdown using selenium webdriver 4.8.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

[image]

I couldn't select the value from the drop-down. Tried with the below mentioned

***Inspect body/html body in attached image:***

***Tried with this***

```
    Select selectBenefeciary = new Select(driver.findElement
            (By.xpath("//*[@id=\"beneficiary\"]")));
    selectBenefeciary.selectByVisibleText("FROBEL ACADEMY");

    Select selectBenefeciary = new Select(driver.findElement
            (By.xpath("//*[@id=\"beneficiary\"]")));
    selectBenefeciary.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than one reasons why selenium is not able to handle the dropdown. One of the reason could be that the script executes faster than the loading of the web page. Try using [Selenium's Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) to effectively locate the element.

Try using `Explicit Waits` something like below:

```
Select selectBeneficiary = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("beneficiary"))));
```

Imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

Comment: Tried with this and getting the same issue :(